# Migration Query

Tags: discussion, migration

https://serverfault.com/questions/246745/the-boss-answer-what-is-a-relational-database

> So could someone give a good "Boss
>   Answer" for what a relational database
>   is? And maybe how its different than
>   just storing data on a file server?

Does this belong on DBA or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hhm. Looking at the upvoted answers at SF. I would none of them describe as 'Boss Answer'. All of them involve too much technical details.

I'm not sure if we here could express it in a more suited way.

I think this question could be assigned with equal right to SO, SF or DBA. It is borderline in any case.

Comment: I'll leave it where it is then. It's about to die as "off-topic", which is probably the most appropriate fate.